# Is it safe to use .serialize() in user input?

Tags: jquery, security, serialization, user-input

Is it safe to use `.serialize()` in user input like in the ajax bellow? I don't know if it's related to security.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'process.php',
    type:'post',
    data: $("#form").serialize()
})
```

I had read somewhere (i think it was here on SO) that `.serialize()` unserialize the data at some point of the request. In PHP it's unsafe to unserialize user input. I don't know how this function `.serialize()` works in javascript, and if it's safe to use in user input.

Comment: That's not a native JavaScript method, but a jQuery one. So, add the relevant tag.

Comment: jQuery `serialize()` creates URL encoded text and I think it is safe. However, you can always do the form validation (default or custom) to sanitize data anyway before `serialize()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can serialize any data securely, including user input. Serialization is just a transformation of something that's already processed in memory to basically a string.

**However** the typical reason you would serialize something is to then deserialize it at some point. Honestly, I can't even think of a different reason. Now **deserializing** user input is insecure, because a string now gets processed when structures are built in memory, and that processing can easily lead to an exploitable vulnerability.

So while your question was about serializing and that part is fine, the necessary other part of deserializing it is not.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `serialize()` creates `URL` encoded text meant to be used in the `HTTP` request. You can always do the `form` validation (default or custom) to sanitize data anyway before `serialize()` is used. If you do so I do not see any security risk.

By the way, there is `serializeArray()`. It produces an array and meant to be used for processing.